# how to attach "fetchpriority" html attribute to images that are included using css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, tags

I have some images that are being defined under css files.
I'm trying to implement "fetchpriority" tag attribute in html to load images faster.
Is there a way that allows to include fetchpriority to those images in css files without mentioning their respective paths in html using  tags.

css:

```
.someCls{
        background-image : url("/path/to/image");
       }
```

I dont want to include image with fetchpriority like this:

```
<link rel="preload" fetchpriority="high" as="image" href="path/to/image">
```

Comment: [`fetchpriority` is a property of the HtmlImageElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/fetchPriority), whereas you are setting a background image on non-image elements (I presume), so adding the `fetchpriority` attribute wouldn't make any difference anyway. I presume you're trying to ensure that these images are loaded before other images on the page and there are other techniques that can help with this, but you don't want to include the paths to the images in the HTML markup, which limits your options. Why can't you include the image paths in the HTML?

Comment: Sorry it was url('/path/to/image') in CSS. And yeah I searched a bit more about this, and found I can't do it without including image path. And if we want to put high priority to an image that is defined as background in CSS, then we should put rel="preload" to the link tag for the browser to discover the image early so that it can load it with high priority.